# How can i parse html message body using MailKit?

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, email, mailkit

I used OpenPop until now but now change to MailKit and this two properties: `FindFirstPlainTextVersion()` and `FindFirstHtmlVersion()` not exist with MailKit.

The variable allMessages is not OpenPop but now it's `List<MimeKit.MimeMessage>` type.

`lvnf` is a ListView control and when I click on an item it should show in RichTextBox I have the content of a message I clicked on. But this two properites not exist in `MailKit(MimeKit.MimeMessage)`.

```
void lvnf_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    OpenPop.Mime.MessagePart plainText = null;
    OpenPop.Mime.MessagePart html = null;
    var firstSelectedItem = ListViewCostumControl.lvnf.SelectedItems[0];
    try
    {
        StringBuilder builder = new StringBuilder();
        if (allLoadedMessages != null)
        {
           plainText  = allLoadedMessages[firstSelectedItem.Index].FindFirstPlainTextVersion();
        }
        if (allMessages != null)
        {
            plainText = allMessages[firstSelectedItem.Index].FindFirstPlainTextVersion();
        }
        if (plainText != null)
        {
            // We found some plaintext!
            builder.Append(plainText.GetBodyAsText());
        }
        else
        {
            // Might include a part holding html instead
            if (allLoadedMessages != null)
            {
                html = allLoadedMessages[firstSelectedItem.Index].FindFirstHtmlVersion();
            }
            if (allMessages != null)
            {
                html = allMessages[firstSelectedItem.Index].FindFirstHtmlVersion();
            }
            if (html != null)
            {
                // We found some html!
                builder.Append(html.GetBodyAsText());
            }
        }
        richTextBox1.Text = builder.ToString();
    }
    catch(Exception err)
    {
        string myer = err.ToString();
    }
}
```

What i tried so far is to create a new class `HtmlPreviewVisitor` and added the class example from the mailkit site:

[mailkit](http://www.mimekit.net/docs/html/WorkingWithMessages.htm)

Then using it in `form1`:

```
void Render(MimeKit.MimeMessage message)
{
    HtmlPreviewVisitor pv = new HtmlPreviewVisitor(tempDirectory);
    pv.Visit(message);
    var tmpDir = Path.Combine(Path.GetTempPath(), message.MessageId);
    var visitor = new HtmlPreviewVisitor(tmpDir);

    Directory.CreateDirectory(tmpDir);

    message.Accept(visitor);
    richTextBox1.Text = visitor.HtmlBody;
}
```

And using the Render like this:

```
void lvnf_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    MimeKit.MimeMessage message = null;
    var firstSelectedItem = ListViewCostumControl.lvnf.SelectedItems[0];
    try
    {
        message = allMessages[firstSelectedItem.Index];
        Render(message);
    }
}
```

But the result in `richTextBox1` is I see html content and not the text of the body.

For example:

```html
<html>
    <head>
        <meta content="text/html; charset=utf-8" http-equiv="Content-Type"/>
        <title>Magic Quadrant for aPaaS</title>
    </head>
    <body oncontextmenu="return false;">
        <center>
            <!-- Header Table For Web Version -->
            <table align="center" border="0" cellpadding="10" cellspacing="0" width="660">
                <tbody>
                    <tr>
                        <td align="center" style="font-family:Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif; font-size:12px; color:#333;">
                            To view a web version of this message, <A TARGET="_blank" HREF="http://clicks.slashdot.org/c.html?ufl=4&amp;rtr=on&amp;s=x8pb08,2jot2,54g,7zdr,51ie,5vra,3kxd&amp;MLM_MID=4277846&amp;MLM_MLID=6640&amp;MLM_SITEID=2010001400&amp;MLM_UNIQUEID=4300628cb1">click here</A></td>
                    </tr>
                </tbody>

...
```

Comment: i haven't used MailKit yet but i have done a windows service that use ActiveUp to read html from email, are you interested?

Comment: Lorenzo yes. I would like to try it use it in my code.

Answer (score 2):

You can use the `TextBody` and/or `HtmlBody` properties to get the equivalent of what you'd get with the methods you mentioned from OpenPop.

Like this:

```
void Render (MimeKit.MimeMessage message)
{
    var tmpDir = Path.Combine(Path.GetTempPath(), message.MessageId);
    var visitor = new HtmlPreviewVisitor(tmpDir);

    Directory.CreateDirectory(tmpDir);

    message.Accept(visitor);

    // Note: You will need to convert HTML into RTF
    var rtf = ConvertHtmlToRtf (visitor.HtmlBody);

    // Use the Rtf property instead of the Text property because
    // the Text property does not support RTF formatting commands.
    richTextBox1.Rtf = rtf;
}
```

Comment: I tried to use the example in the MailKit site the HtmlPreviewVisitor class. I created new class in my project and added the HtmlPreviewVisitor and then using it in form1 like they show.

Comment: jstedfast i also updated my question now with what i tried and what i'm getting as result. What am i missing ?

Comment: You should not use `HtmlBody` *and* `HtmlPreviewVisitor`, you need to choose to use one or the other. Also your code isn't even using the results from `HtmlPreviewVisitor` at all. Secondly, RichTextBox is meant to display RichText formatted text, not HTML formatted text which is why it looks like raw HTML.

Comment: Disregard my last comment except for the fact that RichTextBox does not know how to render HTML so you are using the wrong control. If you want an actual example of code that renders HTML, take a look at the sample program included with MimeKit: https://github.com/jstedfast/MimeKit/blob/master/samples/MessageReader/MessageReader/MessageViewWindow.cs

Comment: @jstedfast i cannot get an inline image that is having src url and not as base 64 or content type image. Can you point me out to any example how i can do it.

Comment: You'd have to show me what the raw email message looks like so I know what you are talking about.

Answer (score 0):

Using ActiveUp this is the class that instantiate the connection and has the method to read

```
 using System.Collections.Generic;
    using System.Linq;
    using ActiveUp.Net.Mail;
    using ActiveUp.Net.Security;
    using System.Diagnostics;
    using System;

namespace servizioWiki
{
    class readMail
    {
        public Imap4Client client = new Imap4Client();
        public readMail(string mailServer, int port, bool ssl, string login, string password)
        {

            if (ssl)
            {
                client.ConnectSsl(mailServer, port);
            }
            else
            client.Connect(mailServer, port);
            client.Login(login, password);
        }
        public IEnumerable<Message> GetAllMails(string mailBox)
        {
            return GetMails(mailBox, "ALL").Cast<Message>();
        }
        public IEnumerable<Message> GetUnreadMails(string mailBox)
        {
            return GetMails(mailBox, "UNSEEN").Cast<Message>();
        }
        protected Imap4Client Client
        {
            get { return client ?? (client = new Imap4Client()); }
        }
        private MessageCollection GetMails(string mailBox, string searchPhrase)
        {
            try
            {
                Mailbox mails = Client.SelectMailbox(mailBox);
                MessageCollection messages = mails.SearchParse(searchPhrase);
                return messages;
            }
            catch(Exception ecc)
            {
                EventLog Log = new EventLog("Application");
                Log.Source = "ServizioWiki";
                Log.WriteEntry("Errore durante la lettura delle mail, dettagli: " + ecc.Message, EventLogEntryType.Warning);
                return null;
            }

        }

    }
```

On my service:

```
read = new readMail(
                            "some.mail.server",
                            port,
                            true,
                            this.username,
                            this.password
                        );
                ...

                var emailList = read.GetAllMails(this.folderEmail);
                Mailbox bbb = read.client.SelectMailbox(this.folderEmail);
                int[] unseen = bbb.Search("UNSEEN");
                foreach (Message email in emailList)
                {
                    byte[] array0 = Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(email.BodyText.Text);
                    EmbeddedObjectCollection immagini_mail = email.EmbeddedObjects;
                    MimePartCollection immagini_mail2 = email.UnknownDispositionMimeParts;
                    string HtmlEmail+= email.BodyHtml.Text.ToString();
                    string TextEmail= email.BodyText.Text.ToString();
                    if (immagini_mail.Count > 0)
                    {
                      //do something with images

                    }
                }
```

Basically you can get the plain text or the html of the email and the attachments
hope this helps, let me know

Comment: What is the contento variable ? contenuto += email.BodyHtml.Text.ToString(); i can't figure out how to declare it what namespace.

Comment: see my edits, it is a string, basically email.BodyHtml.Text gives you the html of the email and the ToString() returns it as a string